# Is fiber product of two affine varieties the same as Cartesian product as sets?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I am learning about fiber products at the moment and I was wondering about the following. 
Suppose I have affine varieties $X, Y$ over an algebraically closed field $k$. 
Say $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{A}^m$, and I'm thinking as a subset of $k^n$ and $k^m$ respectively. 
Is it then the case that $X \times_k Y$ as a set equal to the 
Cartesian product of $X \times Y \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{n+m}$?

Comment: Sure and the Topology must be the Zariski Topology of X\times Y and not the product Topology that is strictly more fine that the Zariski Topology

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Thank you for this. Could you possibly show this as an answer by any chance? I'm struggling to see how this follows from the definition of the fiber product..